# Not added base template paths in Symfony2.1

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

Templating not found form_div_layout.html.twig

Path in twig loader:

```
Array ( [0] => /var/www/nrp.new-generation.com.ua/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views )
```

Why not added default paths?

Error:

```
Unable to find template "form_div_layout.html.twig" in Service:AbstractService::layout.html.twig at line 27.
```

Twig_Loader_Exception:

```
Twig_Error_Loader: Unable to find template "form_div_layout.html.twig" (looked into: /var/www/{path}/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views).
```

EDIT:

I replace default TemplateNameParser in TwigLoader for add me logik load templates.

My TemplateNameParser:

```
    <?php

namespace NRP\Bundles\ServiceBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateNameParser as BaseTemplateNameParser,
    Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateReferenceInterface;

/**
 *
 */
class TemplateNameParser extends BaseTemplateNameParser
{
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function parse($name)
  {
    if ($name instanceof TemplateReferenceInterface) {
      return $name;
    }
    else if (isset($this->cache[$name])) {
      return $this->cache[$name];
    }

    // If not service prefix
    if (strpos($name, 'Service:') !== 0) {
      return parent::parse($name);
    }

    // Find template
    $name = str_replace(':/', ':', preg_replace('#/{2,}#', '/', strtr($name, '\\', '/')));

    if (false !== strpos($name, '..')) {
      throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Template name "%s" contains invalid characters.', $name));
    }

    $parts = explode(':', $name);
    if (4 !== count($parts)) {
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Template name "%s" is not valid (format is "Service:{ServiceName}:{Section}:{template}.{format}.{engine}").', $name));
    }

    $elements = explode('.', $parts[3]);
    if (3 > count($elements)) {
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Template name "%s" is not valid (format is "Service:{ServiceName}:{Section}:{template}.{format}.{engine}").', $name));
    }

    $engine = array_pop($elements);
    $format = array_pop($elements);

    $template = new TemplateReference($parts[1], $parts[2], implode('.', $elements), $format, $engine);

    if (!$template->hasService()) {
      throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Not found service "%s".', $template->get('service')));
    }

    return $this->cache[$name] = $template;
  }
}
```

And add to services:

```
<!-- Twig file system loader -->
<service id="nrp.twig.name_parser" class="NRP\Bundles\ServiceBundle\Twig\TemplateNameParser">
  <argument type="service" id="kernel" />
</service>
<service id="twig.loader" class="Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Loader\FilesystemLoader">
  <argument type="service" id="templating.locator" />
  <argument type="service" id="nrp.twig.name_parser" />
</service>
```

If disabled this loader, all OK!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem solved!

Solution:

Replace parameter templating.name_parser.class;

Example:

```
<parameters>
    <!-- Parameter for TemplatingNameParser -->
    <parameter key="templating.name_parser.class">NRP\Bundles\ServiceBundle\Twig\TemplateNameParser</parameter>
  </parameters>
```